# Tips for rapid .NET application development

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

What are everyones best tips for using VS2010 to develop rapidly in .NET?  So as not to make this too broad, I'm looking for things like:

- Use the 'Ctrl K + D' shortcut combination to automatically format the current code page
- Select multiple lines of code and use 'Ctrl K + C' to comment them all out at once
- Create 'code snippets' to allow quick insertion of custom code and use "Ctrl K + Ctrl X" to quickly access them in the code editor

I'm not asking for example about tools for automatic code generation or best practices being used (e.g. using a business and data layer), rather specifically about the quick 'tips' that we can use throughout everyday development in VS2010 to make coding quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't already know how to locate the VS 2010 short cut key cheat sheet, [here it is](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx)

These are a few of my most used.

### Navigation

My favouriate for navigation and jumping back and forth between code would be Ctrl + '-' and Ctrl + Shift + '-'. These jump back and forward respectively to different parts of code you have edited or focused on. This works across files as well which helps if you are doing a piece of work that is spread across classes.

Ctrl + ',' is also good for jumping to classes, methods or properties you know the name of. This provides an auto filter page of all your solution.

Ctrl + Tab and Ctrl + Shift + Tab works as expected to alternate between your open code files. These keys work in many windows applications.

### Auto complete

A few of my favourite auto complete features are 'ctor' and 'prop'. If you type these within a C# context for example and hit 'Tab' twice, 'ctor' for example will generate a default constructor and 'prop' will stub a property. This also works for things like 'switch', 'for', 'foreach' etc. Just try it out!

For web work, this use of double 'Tab' key also works with a lot of html elements. Eg, type 'div' and hit 'Tab' twice will create a div element. 'ul' will create a list with a single 'li'. Most html elements will generate some valid html for you with just the element name + 'Tab' + 'Tab'.

Comment: Good answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for - the less well-known but very useful tricks.